# How to cast java.sql.Date to java.lang.CharSequence?

Tags: java, android

That's the formatdate method used :

```
private static java.util.Date formatDate(String webPublicationDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    java.util.Date convertedDate = new java.util.Date();

    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(webPublicationDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in the same class there's :

```
Date webPublicationDate = (Date) formatDate(date);
```

In the adapter class I'm using this to setText :

```
publishDate.setText((CharSequence) currentArticle.getPublishDate());
```

Which is giving me an error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Comment: Try this: publishDate.setText(String.valueOf(currentArticle.getPublishDate()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are you sure, that `currentArticle.getPublishDate()` returns the formatted String? If not, try to apply your `#formatDate(currentArticle.getPublishDate())`

2) You shouldn't misstake java.util.Date with java.sql.Date

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CharSequence date = "1996/12/25";
        CharSequence formattedDate = date.subSequence(8, 10) + "/" + date.subSequence(5, 7) + "/"
                + date.subSequence(0, 4);

        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you described is due to the `currentArticle.getPublishDate()` function returning an object of type `java.sql.Date`. You should be able to perform `currentArticle.getPublishDate().toString()` to get the result that you want.